# old wallet is gone after using new Ledger with old seed

Tags: ledger, tezbox

I created Tezbox wallet with Ledger Nano S more than a year ago and then delegate it to a baking service.
It was working good and I used it many times. I didn't login for the last 6 months as this is my longterm Holding.
When I tried to login recently for the first time after Babylon upgrade, it was throwing an error message saying password is incorrect(looks like this is a known issue).
My ledger had old firmware 1.4.2 and also Tezos wallet was old one.
So, I got a new Ledger with latest firmware and logged into it using Seed code, all other apps wallets were imported fine except Tezos.
Tezos wallet has come up with a different wallet address and zero balance.
I think this is something to do with Derivation path issue as I didnt use any derivation path when The wallet was created for the first time in Ledger more than a year ago.
Could some one please help me with how to resolve this issue?
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: how does he do this step by step. Im facing the same problem. I had a tezbox which I migrated into the ledger. But if there's a 24 word seed on the ledger and I have a tezbox wallet which was comprised of a 15 word seed. how do you untangle this spagheetti?

Answer (score 0):

Tezbox and Ledger live both use 44'/1729'/0'/0' as default derivation paths.

I'm guessing what happened is your long term holding address was a 'KT' contract account. If it is actually a KT contract account, then you should be able to use tezbox to "add contract" and interact with it again. You can also verify this is the case on a block explorer. Punch in your 'tz' account to https://tzstats.com and under the Contracts tab you should see your balance.